# Hibernate Table per concrete class Table behavior

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

Lets say, I have a class `Employee` with the fields `employeeId` and `name`. This is inherited by another class `PermanentEmployee` with the field `salary` and `experience`. I used `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`.
From this I understand that it'll create two tables. one for the Parent class with two columns `employeeId` and `name`. Another table for the child class with four columns. That is `name`,`employeeid`,`salary` and `experience`.
When i try to persist the child object (Permanent Employee) with all four values, it is inserting in the child table. **Only in the child table**. It's not inserting in the parent table.
[1] Is this is the default behaviour? or am i missing anything? do i need entity relationships like `@OneToOne` mapping?
[Side note] I also tried with `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`. This time with Table per subclass, it is creating two tables and foreign key relations for them. And Its inserting in both the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`, the entity will be persisted into a single table, which represents the class of persisted Entity. It could be good for perfomance, because you don't have to make a table joins, while getting an Entity instance. But it also has a disadvantages, for example, the tables are not normalized, modification of parent in hierarchy causes changes in all the child tables. In most cases, this strategy is not recomended, though it is the simpliest one.

As for`OneToOne`, if you mean, that you have to provide relationship between parent class and it's subclasses, then no. It is used to make a relationship between two or more instances, not for the class hierarchy.

Comment: Then what should i have to do, if i need the data to be persisted both in parent and child for this 'Table per class'. Any work around?

Comment: You have to use a different strategy, then jpa will create for you normilized tables with join in selects. If you use hibernate only, you'll see no difference, but if you have some native code with selects, you have to remake your queries to use joins